# CodeIgniter - Form processing is slow, and doesn't return values on error

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to condense my controller a bit, mainly due to URI aesthetics. Right now my controller works, but if there's an error I'm left with **controller/process** which I don't really want to be there, I'd rather it be **add**.

So I attempted to rebuild my controller with

```
public function add()
{
    if ( $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST' )
    {
        if ( $this->form_validation->run('add') === FALSE )
        {
             $this->add(); // reload the method/form for errors.
        }
        else
        {
             $this->_process(); // private function for inserting the data.
        }
    }
    else
    {
    $this->load->view('add_form')
    }
}
```

What happens is the form takes a dreadful long time (only like 5 seconds, but that's still disgustingly horrible), then reloads the form, but no errors are displayed and forms are not repopulating.

I'm feeling like this is a super simple issue that's pure user error, but I can't pick out exactly what I'm doing wrong here that's making this process be so finicky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form fails to load, you are calling the method `add()` again which is probably causing it to keep looping through itself.  I would refactor the code to something like this:

```
public function add()
{
    if ( $this->form_validation->run('add') )
    {
        $this->_process(); // private function for inserting the data.
        redirect('controller_name/method_name');
    }

    $this->load->view('add_form')
}
```

Notice I removed the check to see if there is a POST sent because the form won't validate if there is no `$_POST` var to check it against.  Also, I put in a `redirect()` to send the user to a different method, or even reload the same method, but it will clear the `$_POST` and stop the rest of the method from executing.

Comment: The looping issue makes sense, but if I use redirect() then validation is lost (the re-population of the fields). Which this is a form that has about 25 fields, and I'm sure a user would be pretty PO'd if they had to redo the entire form all over again just because they didn't fill it out. What you said makes sense, and I'll see what I can work with on that. I just figured $this->add() would simply reload the method. Guess not. Thanks.

Comment: I misread what you had said at first, then skimmed over it again and understood it. Thanks.